# Output of passwd -S command

Tags: passwd

Normally when I use `passwd -S $USER` to get the status of a user account, the output is something like following:

```
$USER L 11/10/2015 0 99999 7 -1
```

But I have seen cases such that output is short like this:

```
$USER L
```

What is the reason for having an output similar to the short one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the manual page of `passwd`:

> -S, --status
>
> Display account status information. The status information consists of 7 fields. The first field is the user's login name. The second field indicates if the user account has a locked password (L), has no password (NP), or has a usable password (P). The third field gives the date of the last password change. The next four fields are the minimum age, maximum age, warning period, and inactivity period for the password. These ages are expressed in days.

L indicates the account is locked.  If the other fields are blank, that implies that the account has no date of the last password change, minimum age, maximum age, et cetera.

Comment: I got 'PS'  in the output for password. What does 'S' stands for here ?